# VB.net Listview select

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am having problems with highlighting the found listview item using the code below:

```
If lstMaster.View = View.Details AndAlso lstMaster.Items.Count > 0 Then
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem = lstMaster.FindItemWithText(txtSearchSR.Text, True, 0)

    If lvi IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("found")
        lvi.ListView.Items(0).Selected = True  'Does not seem to work...
    End If

End If
```

How do i highliht the found column?

David

Comment: I see you have an "if statement" which determines if the item should be highlighted. Have you checked the value of lvi to see if the FindItemWithText is actually finding an item.

Comment: gosh darn! Just realized that you have a MsgBox("found")..is that showing up as found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it! :o)**

```
lstMaster.Items(lvi.Index).Selected = True
lstMaster.Select()
lstMaster.SelectedItems.Item(0).EnsureVisible()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
lvi.Selected = True
```

From your snippet,

`lvi.ListView.Items(0)` will always return the first ListViewItem in the listview.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Subitems

```
lvi.Items[0].UseItemStyleForSubItems = false
lvi.Items[0].SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Black     
lvi.Items[0].SubItems[0].ForeColor = Color.White
```

if that doesn't work try

```
lvi.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false
lvi.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvi,"subitem", Color.Black, Color.White, lvi.Font ))
```